# WPF Waiting for animation to end before handling event

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-animation

Suppose I have a circular button on a screen that I want to animate the effect of tapping it on. Initially the button (ellipse) background (Fill) is transparent and the border brush (the outline) has some colour and thickness to it to make it look like a button.

Now, I want to animate the background (fill) of this ellipse when a stylus or a mouse enters it to give it that effect if you tap it (you seen it on iphones and other devices).

I created a style in app resources:

```
<Style x:Key="circularButton" TargetType="Ellipse">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="StylusEnter">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard FillBehavior="Stop">
                    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Ellipse.Fill).Color" From="Transparent" To="#993C5E66" Duration="00:00:00.2" />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="StylusLeave">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Ellipse.Fill).Color" From="#993C5E66" To="Transparent" Duration="00:00:00.2" />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Ellipse.Fill).Color" From="Transparent" To="#993C5E66" Duration="00:00:00.2" />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeave">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Ellipse.Fill).Color" From="#993C5E66" To="Transparent" Duration="00:00:00.2" />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>                
        </EventTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

And then subscribed to the ''StylusDown''/''MouseDown'' event to actually handle the button press. The button press launches another form. Problem is that I want to wait for animation to complete before launching this form. Is something like this possible?

Comment: Did you try just putting sleep in the event handler?  And it is not a form in WPF.  And you probably want to cancel in the leave.

Comment: Is cancelling the event (e.g. e.Handled=true) really necessary?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Storyboard.Completed event :

Put a Duration of 00:00:01.2 to see that it indeed doesn't open before the animation is done.

You can of course improve this for this example i decided that leaving the circle means not opening the popup.

XAML :

```
  <Window>
      <Window.Resources>

         <Storyboard FillBehavior="Stop" x:Key="StylusEnterSB" Completed="Storyboard_Completed">
            <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Ellipse.Fill).Color" From="Red" To="#993C5E66" Duration="00:00:00.2" />
         </Storyboard>

         <Storyboard x:Key="StylusLeaveSB" Completed="Storyboard_Completed">
            <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Ellipse.Fill).Color" From="#993C5E66" To="Transparent" Duration="00:00:00.2" />
         </Storyboard>

         <Storyboard x:Key="MouseEnterSB" Completed="Storyboard_Completed">
            <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Ellipse.Fill).Color" From="Red" To="#993C5E66" Duration="00:00:00.2" />
         </Storyboard>

         <Storyboard x:Key="MouseLeaveSB" Completed="Storyboard_Completed"> 
            <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Ellipse.Fill).Color" From="#993C5E66" To="Red" Duration="00:00:00.2" />
         </Storyboard>

         <Style x:Key="circularButton" TargetType="Ellipse">
            <Style.Triggers>
               <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="StylusEnter">
                   <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource StylusEnterSB}" />                      
                </EventTrigger>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="StylusLeave">
                  <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource StylusLeaveSB}" />                       
                </EventTrigger>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter" >
                  <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource MouseEnterSB}" />                        
                </EventTrigger>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeave">
                   <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource MouseLeaveSB}" />                   
                </EventTrigger>
           </Style.Triggers>
       </Style>     
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>      
    <Ellipse Style="{StaticResource circularButton}" Width="25" Height="25" Fill="Red"  MouseLeftButtonUp="Ellipse_MouseLeftButtonUp" MouseLeave="Ellipse_MouseLeave" MouseLeftButtonDown="Ellipse_MouseLeftButtonDown" MouseEnter="Ellipse_MouseEnter"     />      
</Grid>
```

CS:

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    Popup w = new Popup();  
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        w.Height = 200;
        w.Width = 200;
        w.Child = new Rectangle() { Fill = Brushes.Red, Stretch = Stretch.Fill };
        w.Placement = PlacementMode.Right;
        w.PlacementTarget = this;   
    }

    bool canPress = false;      
    private void Storyboard_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        canPress = true;

        if(isMouseDown)
        {
            w.IsOpen = true;
            isMouseDown = false;
        }
    }


    bool isMouseDown = false;
    private void Ellipse_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (isMouseDown && canPress)
        {
            w.IsOpen = true;
            isMouseDown = false;
        }

    }

    private void Ellipse_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        isMouseDown = true;
    }

    private void Ellipse_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        isMouseDown = false;
        canPress = false;
                _currentEllipse = (Ellipse)sender;
    }

    private void Ellipse_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        w.IsOpen = false;       
                    _currentEllipse = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to get a reference to the storyboard from the specific ellipse? I would rather not have a global storyboard complete event to handle but instead attach to the specific ellipse and then its storyboard.

Comment: I wasn't able to do what you specified . but you can check in the global event handler if the ellipse is the sender.

Comment: Thanks, I'll see if I can tinker with it a bit more and post my findings.

Comment: let me know if you find out how to assign the event for a specific ellipse .

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are opening the form and animation in the event handler. By default ui event handlers are called in the UI thread ( The only thread  of the application ) and thus the UI update and all other event handlers task are being done synchronously. Since your event handler is waiting for the form to finish, so the thread is paused until the form is closed. To get rid of such situation you could either use -

1. `Event / Delegates`: Inside the object create another event handler and attach it to a custom event, just to open the form and then when the event handler is called fire that event and open the ui in the second event handlers. So when the first event handler is called it will spawn the form opening code in a new thread and it itself can continue updating the ui. However this is the old approach before `Async/Await` and you will also need some extra work to update UI if anything is needed to be changed in the UI from the child thread.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5z57dxz2(v=vs.90).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5z57dxz2%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

1. Use `Async/Await`  of the new freatues. Here is a link to it -

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx

personally I would go for the Async/Await option, since its efficient and also does not give you the overhead of updating the UI from separate thread.

Comment: I realise that, but I am not sure this is exactly the problem. I am not waiting for the form to finish doing its thing, basically I want the tap animation to happen and then to pop open the form. However, I have no way it seems to reference the storyboard that contains the animation directives as that's loosely coupled via the style reference for the button/ellipse.